# emberjs: You are running a production build of Ember on localhost

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember-rails gem and upgrade from rc1 to rc3. Now I get this warning:

> You are running a production build of Ember on localhost and won't receive detailed error messages. If you want full error messages please use the non-minified build provided on the Ember website.

What configurations do I need to change to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your development.rb file you should specify:

```
config.ember.variant = :development
```

And in your production.rb file:

```
config.ember.variant = :production
```

Comment: How are you starting your rails server? Are you in development mode?

Comment: I think it may have been a cache issue. The production build warning went away when I cleared the cache. I'll play around with it more to make sure...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reference the development version of Ember: https://raw.github.com/emberjs/ember.js/release-builds/ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js