# You are running a production build of Ember on localhost and won't receive detailed error messages

Tags: ember.js

I get this error no matter what version of ember I use, I found one other question on Stackoverflow about this, but they were using some rails stuff whereas I am using Node.js.

The current build of ember I am using is linked here

http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.js

There is no other info I can find on this, any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [emberjs: You are running a production build of Ember on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760377/emberjs-you-are-running-a-production-build-of-ember-on-localhost)

Comment: @MikeW As I have said, **I found one other question on Stackoverflow about this, but they were using some rails stuff whereas I am using Node.js.**

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out and it seems as though the error message is **very** deceiving, because it says that you are using a production build of **Ember.js** when in fact the error originates from **Ember-data.js**.

So to fix this error make sure you have both development builds of **Ember.js** & **Ember-data.js**