# Wrong ember data version used by ember cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to roll back to `v1.0.0-beta.16` after having used `v1.0.0-beta.17`.

I uninstalled version `.17` and installed version `.16`, which seems to have worked according to npm:

```
    $ npm list --depth=0
    ...
    ├── ember-data@1.0.0-beta.16
    ...
```

But when I run ember it still seems to use version `.17` according to the Chrome console:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: which  version of ember-data is mentioned in your package.json? Also try clearing the cache or try in incognito mode in chrome.

Comment: `"ember-data": "^1.0.0-beta.11"`

Comment: try clearing the cache or try in incognito mode in chrome

Comment: try correcting the ember-data version in package.json and then run npm install in the project folder.

Comment: Sure, worth a shot.  One minute

Comment: No luck :/  Last thing I'll try for today is a reboot.  Thanks for all the help man!

Comment: No luck with the reboot either :/

Comment: hey, just look at the warning that you are getting, and look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821716/you-are-running-a-production-build-of-ember-on-localhost-and-wont-receive-detai This may be related. I'm not sure though. Try using the development builds of ember js and ember-data js

Comment: I have an alias set up for when inexplicable things like this happen: `alias nuke='echo "nuking npm and bower..." && rm -rf node_modules bower_components tmp dist && npm cache clean && bower cache clean'`. Then: `npm install && bower install &&`ember build`

Comment: What is your ember data version specified in `bower.json`?

Comment: @JakubNiechciał You're a genius!  I changed the version in `bower.json` to `.16`, and everything's working now.  If you put your comment in an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the help Inquisitive and steveax, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the version in both `package.json` and `bower.json` files. Bower stands for managing your plain JS or CSS assets and `ember-data` is one of them. On the other hand, npm packages will need `ember-data` and specify it in your `package.json` also. Just always remember to change versions of plain JS files in both of them.